# Diagonally iterate a matrix in all possible directions in the cleanest and most compact way in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, matrix, iteration

So I'm trying to write a function that can iterate any matrix (square or not) diagonally with configurable left to right or right to left iteration, diagonal along which the matrix is iterated and top to bottom or bottom to top iteration. I did come up with a function that successfully iterates a matrix diagonally left to right, bottom to top along either diagonal

```js
function iterateDiagonally(matrix, main, rightToLeft, topToBottom)
{
  for(let a = 0, b = matrix.length + matrix[0].length - 1; a < b; ++a)
  {
    let x = main ? Math.min(a, matrix.length - 1) : Math.max(0, a - matrix[0].length + 1);
    let y = main ? Math.min(matrix[0].length - 1, matrix.length + 1 - a) : Math.min(a, matrix[0].length - 1);
    for(let c = 0, d = Math.min(y + 1, main ? x + 1 : matrix.length - x); c < d; ++c)
    {
      let eX = main ? x - c : x + c;
      let eY = y - c;
      console.log(matrix[eX][eY]);
    }
  }
}
/*
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
*/
console.log("Along the main diagonal");
iterateDiagonally([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], true);
console.log("Along the antidiagonal");
iterateDiagonally([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], false);
```

but realized that also making the first 2 parameters variables would make the (already bulky code) look much bulkier. Thus I'm looking for a more clean, compact and no less efficient solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've created an alternative implementation for you that's very simple.

Always start on the top row, and either start at the top or bottom depending on the boolean passed in. Then, we begin an iteration loop, always incrementing x, and either incrementing or decrementing y. On each iteration, check whether the point is out of bounds (this is the terminating condition). Then, add the value at that position to the results array.

```
const board = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]

const pointInbounds = (x, y, board) => (
    x >= 0 
    && x < board[0].length
    && y >= 0 
    && y < board.length
)

const diagonalTraversal = (board, bottomToTop=false) => {
  let y = bottomToTop ? board.length-1 : 0, 
    x = 0

  const values = []
  while(pointInbounds(x, y, board)) {
    values.push(board[y][x])
    x++
    y += bottomToTop ? -1 : 1 
  }
  return values
}

diagonalTraversal(board)
```

By default it will traverse the board from the top left point to the bottom right. If given a true boolean as a second argument, it will start at the bottom left and traverse up to the right.

Comment: That’s not quite what I was looking for. I want to iterate every single element in a zigzag kind of pattern, not just the elements of either diagonal

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up finishing it off myself after a lot of thinking. Leaving it here if anyone comes across the same issue. It can look pretty complicated, but the idea is really simple

```js
function iterateDiagonally(matrix, main, rightToLeft, topToBottom)
{
  // Move along half of the perimeter, excluding the duplicate corner element
  // a - first element of each diagonal
  // b - amount of diagonals in total
  for(let a = 0, b = matrix.length + matrix[0].length - 1; a < b; ++a)
  {
    // For the main diagonal, first move right along the x axis starting with the bottom left element, then move up the y axis
    // For the antidiagonal, first move down the y axis starting with the top left element, then move right along the x axis
    let x = main ? Math.min(a, matrix.length - 1) : Math.max(0, a - matrix[0].length + 1);
    let y = main ? Math.min(matrix[0].length - 1, matrix.length + 1 - a) : Math.min(a, matrix[0].length - 1);
    // Invert the starting position and direction of all movement
    if(rightToLeft) x = matrix.length - 1 - x, y = matrix[0].length - 1 - y;
    let diagonal = [];
    // Move along each diagonal
    // c - element of diagonal
    // d - amount of elements in diagonal in total
    for(let c = 0, d = Math.min(rightToLeft ? matrix[0].length - y : y + 1, main !== rightToLeft ? x + 1 : matrix.length - x); c < d; ++c)
    {
      // Invert the diagonal traversal order
      let iC = topToBottom !== rightToLeft ? d - 1 - c : c;
      // X coordinate of the element
      let eX = main !== rightToLeft ? x - iC : x + iC;
      // Y coordinate of the element
      let eY = rightToLeft ? y + iC : y - iC;
      diagonal.push(matrix[eX][eY]);
    }
    console.log(diagonal.join(", "));
  }
}
/*
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
*/
console.log("Parallel main diagonal, left to right, bottom to top");
iterateDiagonally([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], true, false, false);
console.log("Parallel main diagonal, right to left, bottom to top");
iterateDiagonally([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], true, true, false);
console.log("Parallel main diagonal, left to right, top to bottom");
iterateDiagonally([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], true, false, true);
console.log("Parallel main diagonal, right to left, top to bottom");
iterateDiagonally([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], true, true, true);
console.log("Parallel antidiagonal, left to right, bottom to top");
iterateDiagonally([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], false, false, false);
console.log("Parallel antidiagonal, right to left, bottom to top");
iterateDiagonally([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], false, true, false);
console.log("Parallel antidiagonal, left to right, top to bottom");
iterateDiagonally([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], false, false, true);
console.log("Parallel antidiagonal, right to left, top to bottom");
iterateDiagonally([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], false, true, true);
```